# if i have main room and spare room should they be in different tables?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

I am developing a database for a college.

The system should select a room for each course after considering day, time and number of seats.

The college has specific rooms in specific buildings for specific majors.

For example: Computer Science is in building #1 and it has rooms 1001-1010.
 Business is in building #2 and it has rooms 1001-1020.

In some situations (for example all rooms are busy in specific time...etc) then other rooms 2001-2003 in building #2 will be used for Computer Science.

I am not sure if I should create a table for main room and another for spare room or they should be in one  table.

Note : later the system should print the course name, times, room number and in which building.

[part of ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSWU.png)

Comment: the ER is not accurate just to show tables and fields.

Comment: You could have all in the same table and had a field that specifies if its main or spare. If all the fields are the same for main and spare rooms i think its the best aproach.

Comment: I have to print course, hall and in which building. For main room, according to major number I can get the right building number. but if the room is spare, the major is not in the right building. So i need to add two fields one to specify if main or spare room and another field to specify the building number to avoid getting it from relation. this way has many repeated values and it make no benefits of relations . So could u complete your answer how do I print approbate building if they are in the same building? thank u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this. There may be more fields required but these are the essentials to solve your basic problem.

I have assumed that each room can occasionally be used by more than one major, If that's not true, you could use a slightly simpler design.

---

"Major" table (e.g. computer science, business)

Fields:

"MajorID"

"Name"

---

"Course" table (e.g. some course within a major)

Fields:

"CourseID"

"Name"

"MajorID" - foreign key to Major table

---

"Buildings" table

Fields:

"BuildingID"

"Name"

---

"Rooms" table

Fields:

"RoomID"

"Name"

"Capacity" (number of seats)

"BuildingID" - foreign key to Buildings table

---

"AvailableRooms" table. This will define which rooms can be used for which majors when allocating space to a course. Don't get hung up on the idea that each major only uses a specific building. As you pointed out, in reality they don't, because they have extra rooms in other buildings.

Fields:

"MajorID" - foreign key to Majors table

"RoomID" - foreign key to Room table

"Spare" - you can use this as a boolean to indicate whether this is a "spare" room or not. Then your algorithm can take this into account and only choose these rooms if no regular rooms are available for the major that the course is associated with.

---

"CourseRoomAllocation" - this is where your allocation algorithm will record which rooms are actually allocated to which courses, at which times. This might get more complicated but the basics would be like this:

Fields:

"RoomID" - foreign key to Room table

"CourseID" - foreign key to Course table

"BookingStart" start date/time of usage

"BookingEnd" end date/time of usage

---

I imagine the reality will inevitably be a bit more complex than that, but I think that should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: This is great. I will start with your idea to break dawn the relation between building and major. do a new table for "AvailableRooms" and lastly I will work in "CourseRoomAllocation". Thank you very much :D

Comment: I have a question why we create "AvailableRooms"  table  ? why not simply add its fields in rooms table?

Comment: As I said in the question "I have assumed that each room can occasionally be used by more than one major, If that's not true, you could use a slightly simpler design." That's what I meant. If you don't need that flexibility, then just add those fields to the Rooms table. But personally I always design for the future if I can - you may find the college changes how it uses the rooms in future, if they get more students or something. Then you wouldn't have to change the database to meet what is a fairly predictable requirement. But it's entirely up to you.

Comment: @AL3MS how did you get on with this? did my solution help you? If so please upvote and/or accept the answer :-)